# Reading variables via fread and storing via sscanf

Tags: c, scanf, fopen, fread, fclose

I have a file .txt with values of some variable. I need to read them to declarate my variables in main. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define INPUT "input.txt"

int main (void){

    FILE *open_file = fopen(INPUT, "r");

    if (open_file == NULL){
        puts("ERROR.");
    } else {
        puts("SUCCESS.");
    }

    char *buffer;
    int size = ftell(open_file); 
    int read_file = fread(buffer,size,*open_file);
    int Integer1, Integer2;
    while (size != EOF){
        sscanf("%d%d",Integer1, Integer2);
    }


    int close_file = fclose(open_file);
    if (close_file == -1){
        puts("Error in closing file.");
    } else {
        puts("Closing file: SUCCESS.");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Whats is wrong? I have to read every line of my file. For example if my file contains:

```
1
2
```

My scanf should set:

```
Integer1 = 1; 
Integer2 = 2;
```

Comment: 1st problem `fread(buffer,size,*open_file);`, `buffer` is not allocated

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Error messages should be informative and written to stderr.  Instead of `puts("ERROR")`, try `if (open_file == NULL){ perror(INPUT);}`

Comment: `while (size!= EOF)` is an infinite loop, since size can never change inside the loop.

Comment: `ftell` on a newly opened file is probably going to return 0.  `fread` expects 4 arguments, but you only pass it 3.  If you fix the arguments, I expect you're going to have it read `size` values, but `size` is either zero or -1, so..... what are you trying to do?  Why are you using `fread` instead of `scanf`?

Comment: Your edit wrecked the question — removing the call to `fread()` that you were asking about.  That is not allowed — especially not once you have any answers.  I've rolled back to the prior version.  You might add information to the question after you get one or more answers, but even that is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: Could do with an exit and reporting an error when unable to open file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that after the line

`char *buffer;`

the variable `buffer` does not point to any valid memory location. It is a [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

You can either create a fixed size array like this:

`char buffer[100];`

or you can create a dynamically sized memory buffer, like this:

```
if ( fseek( open_file, 0, SEEK_END ) != 0 )
    DoSomethingToHandleError();
long size = ftell(open_file);
if ( fseek( open_file, 0, SEEK_SET ) != 0 )
    DoSomethingToHandleError();
char *buffer = malloc( size );
if ( buffer == NULL )
    DoSomethingToHandleError();
```

Depending on whether you used a fixed-size array or a dynamically allocated buffer, you should change the call to `fread` to one of the following:

`fread( buffer, sizeof(buffer), open_file ); //for fixed size array`

`fread( buffer, size, open_file ); //for dynamically allocated buffer`

Instead of using the function `fread`, you would probably be better off using the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), especially because `sscanf` requires a null-terminated string as input, not binary data. The function `fread` will give you binary data that is not null-terminated, whereas `fgets` will give you a null-terminated string.

Also, change the line

`sscanf("%d%d",Integer1, Integer2);`

to

`sscanf( buffer, "%d%d", &Integer1, &Integer2);`

Before using `Integer1` and `Integer2` afterwards, you should also check the return value of `sscanf` to make sure that both integers were found in the string.

However, if you don't want to handle the memory management and reading in of the file yourself, you can simply use [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), like this:

```
if ( fscanf( open_file, "%d%d", &Integer1, &Integer2 ) != 2 )
    DoSomethingToHandleError();
```

But this has the disadvantage that `fscanf` will just give you the first two numbers that it finds in the file, and won't perform much input validation. For example, `fscanf` won't enforce that the two numbers are on separate lines. See the following link for more information on the disadvantages of using `fscanf`:

[A beginners' guide away from scanf()](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112034702/http://www.sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

If you use the function `fgets` as I suggested, then you will need two calls to `fgets` to read both lines of the file. This means that `sscanf` will be unable to find both integers in the same string. Therefore, if you use `fgets`, then you will have to change your program logic a bit, for example like this:

```
#define MAX_INTEGERS 2
char buffer[100];
int integers[MAX_INTEGERS];
int num_found = 0;

while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), open_file ) != NULL )
{
    int i;

    if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( openfile ) )
    {
        printf( "Error: Line size too long! Aborting.\n" );
        break;
    }

    if ( sscanf( buffer, "%d", &i ) == 1 )
    {
        if ( num_found == MAX_INTEGERS )
        {
            printf(
                "Error: Found too many integers in file! This "
                "program only has room for storing %d integers. "
                "Aborting.\n",
                MAX_INTEGERS
            );
            break;
        }

        //add found integer to array and increment num_found
        integers[num_found++] = i;
    }
    else
    {
        printf(
            "Warning: Line without number encountered. This could "
            "simply be a harmless empty line at the end of the "
            "file, but could also indicate an error.\n"
        );
    }
}

printf( "Found the following integers:\n" );

for ( int i = 0; i < num_found; i++ )
{
    printf( "%d\n", integers[i] );
}
```

Instead of using `sscanf`, you may want to use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), as that function allows you to perform stricter input validation.

If you don't want to use the function `fgets`, which reads input line by line, but really want to read the whole file at once using `fread`, you can do that, but you would have to add the terminating null character manually.

---

EDIT: Since you stated in the comments that you didn't want a loop and wanted to store the individual lines each into their own named variable, then you could use the following code instead:

```
//This function will assume that one number is stored per line, and
//write it to the memory location that "output" points to. Note that
//the return value does not specify the number found, but rather
//whether an error occurred or not. A return value of 0 means no error,
//nonzero means an error occurred.

int get_number( FILE *fp, int *output )
{
    char buffer[100];
    int i;

    //read the next line into buffer and check for error
    if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp ) == NULL )
        return -1;

    //make sure line was not too long to fit into buffer
    if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( fp ) )
        return -1;

    //parse line and make sure that a number was found
    if ( sscanf( buffer, "%d", &i ) != 1 )
        return -1;

    *output = i
    return 0;
}
```

Now, in your function `main`, you can simply use the following code:

```
int error_occurred = 0;

if ( get_number( &Integer1 ) != 0 )
{
    printf( "Error occured when reading the first integer.\n" );
    error_occurred = 1;
}

if ( get_number( &Integer2 ) != 0 )
{
    printf( "Error occured when reading the second integer.\n" );
    error_occurred = 1;
}

if ( !error_occurred )
{
    printf( "The value of Integer1 is: %d\n", Integer1 );
    printf( "The value of Integer2 is: %d\n", Integer2 );
}
```

Comment: And how can I do to read each line of file?

Comment: @joy: I have now added a code example to my answer.

Comment: Yes but every line need to be stored in a named variable. If I do a loop I can't store them

Comment: @joy: I have now added another code example, which does not use a loop and allows you to keep the named variables.

Comment: Corner case: As the last "line", may or may not contain a `'\n'`, `if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL )` is an insufficient test for file's end.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Good point. I believe I have fixed it now.

Comment: I like the fix.  Should you care, an input line like "123 456xyz\n" passes even with junk after the 2nd `int`.  OP likely does not care.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, that is why I pointed out the possibility of using `strtol` in my answer, as it allows stricter input validation. However, I did not add a code example of using it, as this additonal input validation would likely have confused the OP more than helping them.

Comment: @joy: I believe I now understand what you were trying to do with `ftell`. I have rewritten the start of my answer accordingly.

Comment: @joy: I have now also added an alternative solution which only uses `fscanf` instead of `sscanf`. That is probably the simplest solution to your problem, as it does most of the work for you, but it also is the least powerful solution in terms of input validation.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems in your code

1. `fread(buffer,size,*open_file);`, `buffer` is not allocated

   **A)** you have to allocate memory using `malloc` or `calloc` if you use pointers and also free after you are done with it.
   If you want to avoid the headache of allocating and freeing, you better use an array sufficient enough to store the contents.
2. [`fread`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) takes 4 arguments

   **A)** 4th argument is not `FILE` , its `FILE*` , use only `open_file` not `*open_file` and you have not used `nmemb`(number of members) parameter
   On success, `fread()`  return the number of items read, so check the return value to avoid errors.
3. [`ftell()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell) returns the current offset , Otherwise, -1 is returned
   **A)** you really don't need it, check the return value of `fread` to find out you have reached the EOF.
4. check the syntax of [`sscanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell) and [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm)

Answer (score 1):

OP's code failed to seek the end of the array, allocate space for `buffer` and used `fread()` incorrectly.
Correct version shown with some error checking.

```
//char *buffer;
//int size = ftell(open_file); 
//int read_file = fread(buffer,size,*open_file);

// Seek and report, hopefully, the end position
if (fseek(open_file, 0, SEEK_END)) { fprintf(stderr, "fseek() failed.\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE;
long size = ftell(open_file); 
if (size == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "ftell() failed.\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }

// Allocate memory and read
if ((unsigned long) size > SIZE_MAX) { fprintf(stderr, "size too big.\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
char *buffer = malloc((size_t) size);
if (buffer == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
size_t length = fread(buffer, sizeof *buffer, size, open_file);

// Use `length` as the number of char read
// ...
// when done
free(buffer);
```

---

Other problems too.

```
// while (size != EOF){
//    sscanf("%d%d",Integer1, Integer2);
// }
```

Maybe later, GTG.